# Best way to debug SQL queries in Acumatica

Tags: sql, debugging, acumatica

How can I monitor the SQL queries generated by Acumatica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can monitor lots of things such as SQL and Memory through the Request Profiler.

Go to: System-->Management-->Request Profiler

There is a check box to turn on SQL Logging.

Enable Logging + Enable SQL logging then go and do something that causes data to load. Then come back to this screen and click refresh and you will see the actions performed. You can select an action and click SQL to see the SQL for that action.

Remember to turn it off when you are done as it will have a small performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can drill down to "Performance Tools" --> SQL Server Profiler.

Using the SQL Server Profiler you can start a trace of the database your system is attached to.

By performing the action you want to watch, you will see the trace fill with queries caused by the action. You can then pause the trace and dissect each query and figure out what is going on.

You can filter the types of things you see in the trace. And by selecting a row, the query or action executed shows the details in the display at the bottom. You can then copy and paste that into a query editor of your choice and discover.